# Getting Permission denied when Running collectstatic in Django in ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When running the following command I am getting this error: `Permission denied: '/opt/python/bundle/4/app/staticfiles'`

```
source /opt/python/current/env && python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Here are my settings:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: You may run it as a `root`. Can you change to root when you ssh into the instance, `sudo su`?

Comment: that worked! is there a reason why it happens? I remember deploying django apps to EB before and running the commands as a root wasn't required

Comment: you can inspect the folder permissions using `ls -la`. Everything in the folders you want will be under either `root` or `wsgi` (at least in my case). If you don't mind I can provide answer for future reference?

Comment: yeah of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The folder `/opt/python/current` links to one of the folders in `/opt/python/bundle`. These folders are under `root` ownership.

Thus the solution was to use root to run the command.

Comment: Hi @Marcin! I have noticed that since I started using `sudo su` before the collectstatic command, every deploy takes singnificantly longer. Do you have any idea what that happens?

Comment: I could potentially change the staticfiles folder permissions to wsgi and I think that would solve that problem. Do you by change know the command to do that?

Comment: @Anatol `chown -R wsgi.wsgi <folder>` - this changes owner of every file and folder  in <folder> to user wsgi and group wsgi.